# Unreal Engine 4.18 Set IOS icons [IOS11]

Tags: icons, ios11, unreal-engine4

In the project settings I have replaced all the default Unreal icons with my custom ones of the correct sizes, but yet when I build and launch to my phone the default icon is still showing.

Not sure what I am missing here, any help would be amazing. I am using 4.18 so maybe it could be something with the version and it not being very friendly to IOS11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a bug in Unreal Engine 4.18.0, with the new patch 4.18.1, this problem has been fixed.